# Which method is executed to expire Guava cache using expireAfterAccess?

Tags: java, spring, guava, google-guava-cache

I am using Guava cache manager and setting `expireAfterAccess` value. 
I want to know which method is invoked to expire entries from the cache?

Comment: It manages the expiration by itself, that's the point.

Comment: I want to override that method and add one more condition before expiring the cache contents. So, which method exactly check current time and expireAfterAccess parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can't override the implementation of the Guava cache, if it doesn't have an extension point accessible through the [`CacheBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html): all you get is an interface (either [`Cache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) or [`LoadingCache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html)), the implementing classes are private.